# Unable to create directory using FileDataStoreFactory on Android for Youtube Data api v3

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to use [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for my android project. And I guess API Client Library Java now supports Android. I'm following [these samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java). In my [Auth.java](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java) at below line :

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";
File dataDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY);
FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(dataDirectory);
```

I got below error.

> unable to create directory: /.oauth-credentials

I tried to create a directory in sd card with below code :

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

and gave permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but still I can't create directory.

Additionaly versions of libraries I am using:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev162-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: 
`File dataDirectory = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY);`

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: System.getProperty("user.home") returns an empty string and is not useful in android. There for the error: unable to create directory: /.oauth-credentials. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html.  getFilesDir returns application data directory and you can store your credentials there